# ‘Icon Name Must Be Set’ Issue Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following the Udacity course on android programming, and I'm trying to set the icon for the app to the one provided for in the course. When I follow the instruction, the following error prevents me from continuing:

"Icon Name Must Be Set"

I have no missing field on the Configure Image Asset page, so I'm clueless, and googling doesn't seem to help. Anyone have an idea of what's going wrong?

If this helps, heres my gradle sync log

```
4:23:24 PM Gradle sync started
4:23:30 PM Gradle sync failed: failed to find target android-21 : C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
       Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
4:23:30 PM NullPointerException: null
4:23:48 PM IllegalArgumentException: Invalid paths used when trying to generate an icon
```

I also get a `null' ide exception when I start up the project.

Answer (score 1):

use Android SDK Manager to update Android API and then open the IDE and update Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, you have found the answer by now, but I will post what seemed to work for me.

I was using Gradle version 2.10 and the source code for the Sunshine project seems to need 2.02 of Gradle. When I downloaded this older version, I no longer got the weird "Icon Name Must Be Set" issue.

To change the version of Gradle used :

1. Android Studio -> Preferences
2. Build, Execution, Deployment
3. Build Tools
4. Gradle
5. Select the option "User local gradle distribution" and navigate to the location where the gradle version you want to use is located.

Click apply and ok after. That should do it. It worked for me at least.

I am using a Mac (El Cap) with the latest version of Android Studio 2.1.1